# Simple read columns and sum 3rd column

Tags: bash, awk

I am really really stuck on this and would appreciate any help!

I have a 3-column CSV file.  If a row has same 1st column and 2nd column as another row, then add together the 3rd column from these rows.

```
Input:
7514    128    1
7514    128    2
7514    128    1
7514    544    1
7514    544    3
5807    338    4
5807    338    1

Output:
7514    128    4
7514    544    4
5807    338    5
```

I tried

```
awk '{A[$1]+=$2;next}END{for(i in A){print i,A[i]}}' file
```

But it only gives me

```
7514 1472
5807 676
```

Which is not what I want.  Would really appreciate any awk experts' help on this.

Comment: is the data always sorted?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want something like this:

```
awk '{A[$1" "$2]+=$3}END{for(i in A){print i,A[i]}}' file
```

(you don't really need the `next`) as shown in the following transcript:

```
$ echo '7514    128    1
7514    128    2
7514    128    1
7514    544    1
7514    544    3
5807    338    4
5807    338    1' | awk '{A[$1" "$2]+=$3}END{for(i in A){print i,A[i]}}'

7514 128 4
5807 338 5
7514 544 4
```

Your original code summed column 2 based on a key in column 1.

What you need to do (and the above `awk` script does) is to sum column **3** based on a key made from columns **1 and 2**.

---

And, if the data will always be sorted and may have a *lot* of keys (beyond what `awk` can handle), you can simply use:

```
awk 'NR==1           {last=$1" "$2; sum=$3; next}
     last!=$1" "$2   {print last" "sum; last=$1" "$2; sum=0}
                     {sum += $3}
     END             {print last" "sum}'
```

which is your "classic" sorted list processing.

It's not as elegant as the array storage solution so should probably only be used *if* the array is beyond `awk`'s capacity. I include it only for completeness.

Comment: Or one may use `awk`'s multiple subscripts feature: `awk -vSUBSEP=" " '{S[$1,$2]+=$3}END{...}`

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash:

```
declare -A sum                      # an associative array

while read k1 k2 val ; do
  ((sum[$k1-$k2]+=val))             # combine keys to one
done < "$infile"

for k in ${!sum[*]}; do
  echo -e "${k/-/ } ${sum[$k]}"     # separate keys
done
```

Output:

```
7514 544 4
7514 128 4
5807 338 5
```